# How can I check if a float variable value is equal to 1.08?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since the Dissolve effect process finish when the variable value is 1.08 I want at this value to change the object position. but this comparison I did is never true.

```
IEnumerator Teleport(float from, float to, float duration)
    {
        alreadyFading = true;

        var timePassed = 0f;
        while (timePassed < duration)
        {
            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

            var factor = timePassed / duration;
            var value = Mathf.Lerp(from, to, factor);

            foreach (var m in materials)
            {
                m.SetFloat("_DissolveAmount", value);

                if (value == 1.08f)
                {
                    transform.position = teleporters[1].transform.position;
                }
            }

            yield return null;
        }
```

Comment: When comparing with floats you're better off checking if the value is approximately the same by seeing if the absolute difference is less than some acceptable tolerance.

Comment: `if (Math.Abs(value - 1.08) < 1e-8) {...}` - compare with *tolerance* since `value` being a *floating point* can be, say, `1.08000000001` or `1.79999999998`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all floating point numbers are exactly representable. When you add/subtract you may be adding a little bit more (or less) then you think you are. The value you compare against may not be representable either.

You need to compare to an *approximation* of that value. Typically this is done by selecting an epsilon value representing a tolerance that is "close enough" and checking that the absolute difference between the *actual* value and the *target* value is less than that tolerance. For example:

```
const float tolerance = 0.00001f;
if (Mathf.Abs(1.08f - value) < tolerance)
{
   transform.position = teleporters[1].transform.position;
}
```

Alternatively you can make use of Unity's [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html)

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(1.08f, value))
{
   transform.position = teleporters[1].transform.position;
}
```

`Approximately` tests whether the value is within a tolerance of [`Mathf.Epsilon`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html) which is the smallest difference between two floating point numbers. Sometimes this value maybe *too* small. I suggest defining an epsilon yourself such as the first example.

Comment: As correctly mentioned in the answer: **It is extremely unlikely that the value will exactly match during a Lerp over time!** Thus, I wouldn't even bother with checking for an exact value but rather e.g. simply test for `if(value >= 1.08f)`. However I want to also add: I would rather use a check on the `factor` e.g. for `if(factor >= 0.5f)` so you don't depend on the inputs for `from` and `to`.

Answer (score 0):

Floating-point values are imprecise. You should check if the value is within a certain margin of error from `1.08f` instead.

You can define an `EPS` (epsilon) float value and subtract the two floating-point values, get the absolute value of the subtraction and see if it is smaller than EPS. Epsilon is the acceptable tolerance value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, though I'd try converting *value* to temporarily become a rounded-off double, then check if your now double *value* is == to 1.08, as a double.

Comment: No, doubles still suffer from inexactitude (if that were a word). The *epsilon* value may be several orders of magnitude smaller, but you still need it

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple and try:

```
if (value >= 1.08f)
{
  transform.position = teleporters[1].transform.position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As floating numbers are really hard to compare, use in-build functions like this:

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(1.08f,value))
{
    print("The values are approximately the same");
}
```